# how to write frames into folder using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Extracting frames from live webcam video and save in common space. but how to write frames in specific folder using opencv

code :

```
import cv2
# Opens the inbuilt camera of laptop to capture video.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # This condition prevents from infinite looping
    # incase video ends.
    if ret == False:
        break
    # Save Frame by Frame into disk using imwrite method
    cv2.imwrite('Frame'+str(i)+'.jpg', frame)
    i += 1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i tried like this but i wont worked for me

```
out_path = "/home/fraction/Desktop/extract_webcam_frames/frames"
path = out_path 
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path +  str(i)+'.jpg' , frame)
i += 1
```

How to resolve this issue using opencv python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), which is available in Python 3.6+.

```
out_path = f"/home/fraction/Desktop/extract_webcam_frames/frames/Frame{i}.jpg"
cv2.imwrite(out_path, frame)
i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the path correctly.

```
out_path = "/home/fraction/Desktop/extract_webcam_frames/frames"
frame_name = 'Frame'+str(i)+'.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_path, frame_name), frame)
i += 1
```